# hash function to retrieve name and corresponding ID with name as record key

Tags: c++

i want to create a hash function in C++ which returns the surname of a student and his or her corresponding index number when his or her name is entered. the name will be used as the record key and the user should be able to initially enter only 10 names into the system. the array table and the hash table should also be outputted.
i'm totally lost in how to accomplish this. Thanx

Comment: Is this homework? Do you even know how Hashing works.

Comment: Hash functions does not return anything but a digest. By the way, we're not your developers pool. Try to show some code and we would be able to help you getting over your problems. If you don't know what to code because of subject incomprehension, try to show us the complete subject (so we can understand) and ask for suggestion of implementation rather than code, so that you can go on ideas and come back for help if stuck on these.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has [a wealth of information on hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) which should get you started.

If you have specific problems once you've had a crack at an answer, that's the time to come and ask for specific help here on StackOverflow.